# VirtualHost with wildcard VirtualDocumentRoot does not work sometimes

Tags: php, apache, virtualhost, wildcard-subdomain

So i have a website in which there is a form where users fill their details and we have a functionality where the users subsite will gets automatically created for them.
For example, user registers with newres as his username then we create a subsite for them on newres.crm.nadsoftpro.info.

We are using apache server. The general functionality is we dynamically create a virtual host entry through php. We then also create a directory for them in the /var/www/html/ folder dynamically. We then enable the site in the back end and restart the server automatically through cron, so newly added subsite can run without doing manual server restart.

The problem is sometime the subsite gets creates without any issues and loads smoothly. But sometime it does not load. I can see the virtual host is there, directory is there in html folder but when i hit the url in the browser, it just shows the blank page. (Screenshot: https://www.screencast.com/t/y2z41cr4tVVm). While other website is loading correctly through the same script: http://gaurav.crm.nadsoftpro.info.

Here is the virtual host entry for this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
UseCanonicalName Off
ServerName newres.crm.nadsoftpro.info
ServerAlias newres.crm.nadsoftpro.info
VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/html/newres.crm.nadsoftpro.info
<Directory /var/www/html/newres.crm.nadsoftpro.info/>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
Require all granted
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Can someone please help me to figure out what i am missing?
Thank you.

Comment: Same problem. Sometimes loads the WordPress installation screen but if I submit the form or press refresh it loses it and show the global default page.

Comment: I had to change the server for this to work. I moved it to AWS server and now seems to be working fine. Not sure what was the problem.